# Implementing Picard and strong solution for stochastic differential equation in R

Tags: r, stochastic

So, I'm kind of at a loss here as to how to fix this issue. For a homework assignment, I'm supposed to implement two approximations of the geometric Brownian motion and compare them to the explicit solution. In both cases below, W represents a Brownian path I generate seperately with Levy-Ciesielski to be able to gauge the accuracy of the approximations.

Picard:

```
Picard = function(N, m, W){ 
    Pfad = seq(1, 1, length.out=2^m+1); 
    for (i in 1:N){ 
        NeuerPfad = vector(length=2^m+1);
        NeuerPfad[1] = 1;
        for (j in 2:2^m+1){
            NeuerPfad[j] = NeuerPfad[j - 1] + Pfad[j - 1]/(2^m) + 2 * Pfad[j - 1] * (W[j] - W[j - 1]);
        }
        Pfad = NeuerPfad;
    }
    return(Pfad);
}
```

The problem with this one is that the results break apart more and more with every iteration. For some reason, I end up with N zeroes at the start of the path (exempting the initial 1) and I have no idea why that's the case.

Strong solution:

```
StarkeLoesung = function(m, W){
    Pfad = vector(length=2^m+1); 
    Pfad[1] = 1;
    for (i in 2:2^m+1){ 
        Pfad[i] = Pfad[i - 1];
        Pfad[i] = Pfad[i] * (2^(-m) + 2  * (W[i] - W[i - 1]));
    }
    return(Pfad);
}
```

I'm not sure what the problem with this one is at all since it seems to flatout skip the for loop. No matter what I do to this function, all it returns at the end is a vector with a 1 at the start and a whole bunch of zeroes.

Comment: So, after a bit of fiddling around, I did manage to make those functions give me the solutions I want to, though I'm not exactly sure how my solution ended up working. Essentially, creating a sequence of ones makes StarkeLoesung do what I want it to, but starting with a null vector and declaring the first entry to be 1 doesn't, setting aside that even if that did work, the algorithm supplied by the exercise was faulty to begin with.